# Using portrait drawable with xml in drawable-land folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I have

xmlA in drawable and drawable-land folder

xmlB in drawable and drawable-land folder

icon_image in drawable and drawable-land folder

I want to use icon_image in both the xml's

In xmlA it works fine but in xmlB i want to use icon_image of only drawable folder no matter my xml is in landscape mode or portarit mode. I don't want icon_image of drawable to be used

The problem is when application is in landscape mode xmlB uses the icon_image of drawable-land which is default behavior of android, i dont want this to happen.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: but by doing that i xmlA won't get that image for landscape mode.

Comment: have you add  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"in menifest

Comment: Yes i have it works fine, the problem is i don't want xmlB to use drawable-land folder image

Comment: then see the design in land and change the image. :P

Comment: Copying the image or changing the image name is the last thing i want to do. Isn't there any optimize way.

Answer (score 0):

for landscap mode in xmlB remove src or background of ur image view and add the code in activity where u use xmlB

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            setContentView(R.layout.xmlB); 
            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
                      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_image);


    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            setContentView(R.layout.xmlB); 





    }
}
```

do same as in potrait mode for this but using this method u have to do all thing again means set text for textview button click etc... in both potrait and landscape mode may it works